# VS Code CSS syntax highlighting not working anymore after disabling the SASS extension

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

The syntax highlighting and the autocomplete completely stopped working.

I've been trying to find the culprit in the settings but nothing seems to revert the default way of working. My current settings below:

```
{
    "emmet.excludeLanguages": [

        "markdown"
    ],
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "css.hover.documentation": true,
    "[css]": {

        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    },
    "css.styleSheets": [
    
    ]
}
```

[image]

Edit: I fixed it. In the settings.json, the files.associations was missing `"*.css": "css"`

```
  "files.associations": {
        "*.css": "sass",
        "*.css": "css"
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

Go to Settings in VsCode. Search for File Associations:

[image]

Click on Edit in Settings.json and make sure nothing is added for CSS. For me it was tailwind CSS added which was not letting me enable formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You say you fixed it by adding a line mapping the .css file extension to CSS language mode, and showed the following config:

```json
  "files.associations": {
        "*.css": "sass",
        "*.css": "css"
    },
```

In which case I question why you don't just remove the line you have there that for some reason maps the .css file extension to SASS language mode. (hint hint- that's me saying I think you should do that instead. I don't understand why you'd map the .css file extension to SASS in the first place. <insert [math is math meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/math-is-math) here except it's "CSS is CSS">).